# Call node.js function on insert in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, database

I'm using Sql server and i have a function in node.js that i want to be executed everytime a new row is inserted in the specific table.

This is the code that i want to be run when a change is made in the table.

```
private sql = require('mssql');
private currentID: any;

`private config = {
user: 'sa',
password: 'sa',
server: '192.168.100.2',
port: '1433',
database: 'test1',
connectionTimeout: 100000,};
`
public checkDatabase() {
    this.sql.connect(this.config).then((connection: any) => {
        new this.sql.Request(connection).query('SELECT EventID FROM Events ORDER BY EventID DESC').then((recordset: any) => {

            console.log(recordset.recordset[0].EventID);
            if (this.currentID == recordset.recordset[0].EventID) {
                console.log("They are the same " + this.currentID + " " + recordset.recordset[0].EventID);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Not the same " + this.currentID + " " + recordset.recordset[0].EventID);
            }
            this.currentID = recordset.recordset[0].EventID;
        });
    });
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: you should create insert trigger

Comment: In general it's not possible. If a row is inserted out of your application you have no way to be notified. You can try to create decorators for all the save functions though.

Comment: @JúliusMarko can you give me more details please, i don't know much about triggers

Comment: see my answer  below

Comment: Your workflow isn't clear.  Can you describe the logic to be implemented?

Comment: @Serg I am checking if there is a new EventID in the database, everytime a new row is inserted. If it is then i call more functions, but this is the most important one.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the case for the trigger.  You can call Sql procs and functions in a trigger. Trigger can be .Net coded as well

Answer (score 0):

A general way is to create a trigger for insert operation - means that given code will be be executed after every insert in given table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name_of_your_trigger 
ON test1.Events  
AFTER INSERT   
AS  
   /* here you should specify what do you want to do, for instance print something: */
   print "Hello world" 
GO
```

see docs for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql